# How to catch and ignore IncompatibleType Error in Java

Tags: java, types, compilation, try-catch

I have been searching for about 2 hours now and cannot find a way to catch and ignore an incompatible type error in Java. This is compile-time error caused by attempting to assign a float value to an integer. I know why this error is occurring (narrow conversion) and specifically WANT this error to occur as it is for a demonstration of the error itself (needed for a course I am in), but in attempting to catch the error using a try-catch statement I am having no luck.

I know you should specify the error type you are catching, but for the purpose of this code it is okay if I take the generic route here, because everything is pretty well contained and very simple. I would never use this kind of error checking for anything more involved than the purposes of this project, but if you know the exact error type causing the message "error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from float to int" to be displayed when attempting to compile, I'll use that error type. I looked through multiple sites and could not find the exact type of this error (such as IOException, for example).

Here is the code I am trying to execute:

```
import java.lang.*;
public class AssignTests {  

int integer = 10;
float floater = 1234.1234f;

public static void main(String[] args){ 
    AssignTests test = new AssignTests();

    try{
        test.integer = test.floater;
    }
    catch (Exception t)
    {
        System.out.println("An integer cannot be assigned the value of a float.");
    }
  }
}
```

When I go to compile this code I still see the error message of incompatible types despite trying to ignore this issue via the try-catch statement, and after searching for this long on how to resolve this am pretty stumped.

Any idea on how to get this to compile and give me the output message I am looking for?

Comment: You cannot use `try-catch` for compilation errors.

Comment: You can't "catch" compile-time errors--you *fix* them. If you want to demonstrate something, maybe run the compiler from the command line and show the error output?

Comment: Thanks, that really helps! I thought they would be covered under "checked exceptions" but I must have missed that. Guess I'll have to find another way around this issue, appreciate the information.

Comment: @PM77-1 Can you please reference this very fact at the docs. I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: @polendina - `try-catch` work with **runtime** exceptions, which means that compilation already happened prior to that.

Comment: @PM77-1 Was wondering if there was a resource that explicitly state this distinction or at the very least fill in this knowledge gap. I've tried to look it up myself but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of normal conversion

```
test.integer = (int) test.floater;
```

Comment: I know I could typecast, but I wanted to show that it is unable to assign the value without casting. Based on the earlier comments, it looks like I'll have to approach this from another angle. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You cannot `try-catch` for compilation errors.

The incompatible `error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from` is a compile-time error and therefore this is an impossible task without typecasting or other workarounds.

Thanks to PM 77-1 for the response (in comments), figured I'd write it as an answer to close the question.